# html2pdf extension in yii not working correctly

Tags: php, html, pdf, yii, html2pdf

I am using html2pdf in yii. As per guidlines I included following code in config :

```
    'ePdf' => array(
            'class'         => 'ext.yii-pdf.EYiiPdf',
            'params'        => array(
                'HTML2PDF' => array(
                    'librarySourcePath' => 'application.vendor.html2pdf.*',
                    'classFile'         => 'html2pdf.class.php', // For adding to Yii::$classMap
                    /*'defaultParams'     => array( // More info: http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf:en:v4:accueil
                        'orientation' => 'P', // landscape or portrait orientation
                        'format'      => 'A4', // format A4, A5, ...
                        'language'    => 'en', // language: fr, en, it ...
                        'unicode'     => true, // TRUE means clustering the input text IS unicode (default = true)
                        'encoding'    => 'UTF-8', // charset encoding; Default is UTF-8
                        'marges'      => array(5, 5, 5, 8), // margins by default, in order (left, top, right, bottom)
                    )*/
                )
            ),
        ),
```

and I extract needed files in extension and vendors folder, but I am getting an error like

"**include(HTML2PDF_locale.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**".

Please help..what this error means.

Comment: Are you using the normal PHP version of HTML2PDF or a Yii extension? If you're using the normal PHP version put it in your `protected/models/` folder